# Header items with float right = float left How?

Tags: html, css, header

I have three social media buttons with float right en all the buttons have a different width. There is also an h1 at the right side in the header with float right. But my social media button with float right, is not float right but it is at the left side of the header.

```
/*nieuwsbrief*/
#zoekveldandsocial > h1{
color: white;
float: right;
background-color: #e8b215;
font-size: 12px;
height: 15px;
padding: 13px;
text-align: center;
width: 100px;


}

/*facebook*/
#social > img:first-of-type{
width: 2%;
}

/*twitter*/
#social >img:nth-of-type(2){

width: 2%;
}

/*linkedin*/
#social > img:nth-of-type(3){

width: 2.1%;
}


#social{
float: right;

}


<div id="zoekveldandsocial">
<h1>Nieuwsbrief</h1>
<div id="social">
<img src="img/facebook.png" alt="facebook" />
<img src="img/twitter.png" alt="twitter" />
<img src="img/linkedin.png" alt="linkedin" />
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/27zs3nhn/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/27zs3nhn/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try This you need to change the float right to float left of of h1. https://jsfiddle.net/27zs3nhn/

```
  color: white;
    float: left;
    background-color: #e8b215;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;


    }

    /*facebook*/
    #social > img:first-of-type{
    width: 2%;
    }

    /*twitter*/
    #social >img:nth-of-type(2){

    width: 2%;
    }

    /*linkedin*/
    #social > img:nth-of-type(3){

    width: 2.1%;
    }


    #social{
    float: right;

    }


    <div id="zoekveldandsocial">
    <h1>Nieuwsbrief</h1>
    <div id="social">
    <img src="img/facebook.png" alt="facebook" />
    <img src="img/twitter.png" alt="twitter" />
    <img src="img/linkedin.png" alt="linkedin" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code must change to this

```css
/*nieuwsbrief*/
#zoekveldandsocial > h1{
color: white;
float: right;
background-color: #e8b215;
font-size: 12px;
height: 15px;
padding: 13px;
text-align: center;
width: 100px;


}

/*facebook*/
#social > img:first-of-type{
float: right;
width: 2%;

}

/*twitter*/
#social >img:nth-of-type(2){
float: right;
width: 2%;
}

/*linkedin*/
#social > img:nth-of-type(3){
float: right;
width: 2.1%;
}


<div id="zoekveldandsocial">
<h1>Nieuwsbrief</h1>
<div id="social">
<img src="img/facebook.png" alt="facebook" />
<img src="img/twitter.png" alt="twitter" />
<img src="img/linkedin.png" alt="linkedin" />
</div>
```

then it will show you what you desire..

Answer (score 0):

***CSS FILE :***

```
/*nieuwsbrief*/

#zoekveldandsocial > h1 { 
    color: white;
    float: right;
    background-color: #e8b215;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 15px;
    padding: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
}

/*facebook*/
#social > img:first-of-type{
    width: 2%;
}
/*twitter*/
#social >img:nth-of-type(2){
    width: 2%;
}

/*linkedin*/
#social > img:nth-of-type(3){
    width: 2.1%;
}

#social{
    float: left;
}
.socialnetwork{
    display:inline;
    margin:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 10px; 
}
```

***HTML FILE :***

```
<div id="zoekveldandsocial">
    <h1>Nieuwsbrief</h1>
    <div id="social">
        <a href="#" class="socialnetwork"><img src="img/facebook.png" alt="facebook" /></a>
        <a href="#" class="socialnetwork"><img src="img/twitter.png" alt="twitter" /></a>
        <a href="#" class="socialnetwork"><img src="img/linkedin.png" alt="linkedin" /></a>
    </div>
```

I hop this is what you looking for , you can change the margin between the social networks with changing the value of margin.